# Sort Array of objects by property value typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[I am attaching output how i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AQH8.jpg)I have list of objects like below,

```
const list = [{
  "ID": "3",
  "Status": "NEW"
},
{
  "ID": "1",
  "Status": "Open",
},
{
  "ID": "9",
  "Status": "NEW",
},
{
  "ID": "5",
  "Status": "NEW",
},
{
  "ID": "0",
  "Status": "Closed",
},
{
  "ID": "6",
  "Status": "Closed",
}];
```

I want to sort by Status.. as per drop down selection. drop down Array contains [New, Closed, Open]. if I select 'New' Status with 'New' should be on top of list, similarly for 'Open' as well.

I tried list sort like below its giving ascending and descending order not like I want.

```
list.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return a.Status < b.Status ? -1 : a.Status > b.Status ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Please suggest, how can pass property value.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do u want the output to be?

Comment: if New status is top of the list, how about the other 2 statuses?

Comment: Do you want to sort or order by?

Comment: Vandesh , i am sorry i was confused.. how can i do orderby in this case

Comment: Damian, remaining status will be below of that list.

Comment: sortListBy('New'); 
sortListBy(statusValue) {
// here as per status value I want to Sort
list.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return a.Status < b.Status ? -1 : a.Status > b.Status ? 1 : 0;
});
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: I have attached image how I am expecting .. I am able to do ascending or descending order.. not like i want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
const order = ["NEW", "Closed", "Open"];
list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return order.indexOf(a.Status) - order.indexOf(b.Status);
});
```

<sup>(This only works under the assumption that all `.Status` values occur in the `order` array)</sup>

Comment: Hi Bergi,
can I use switch case ? instaed of index of ?  
sortListBy('New');
    sortListBy(statusValue) {
      switch (statusValue) {
        case 'New': {
          list.sort(
            function(a, b) {
                return a.status - b.status;
            });
          break;
        },
        case 'Open': {
          list.sort(
            function(a, b) {
                return a.status - b.status;
            });
          break;
        }
      }
    }

Comment: @PraveenBomminani No, you cannot change the `sort` callback with the `indexOf` call. But of course you can choose the `order` dynamically, using whatever kind of logic you want.

Comment: Got it, Thank you Bergi.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use filter to show all the list values that contain NEW or Open

```js
const list = [{
  "ID": "3",
  "Status": "NEW"
},
{
  "ID": "1",
  "Status": "Open",
},
{
  "ID": "9",
  "Status": "NEW",
},
{
  "ID": "5",
  "Status": "NEW",
},
{
  "ID": "0",
  "Status": "Closed",
},
{
  "ID": "6",
  "Status": "Closed",
}];

const ans = list.filter(e => e.Status === 'NEW');
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, I want all objects in the List but with selected Value. If i pass 'NEW' new status values should be on top remaining will be on after New objects.

Comment: May be bergi's solution suits you.